# Using shadow support in C

Tags: c, gcc

i'd like to shed some light on this shadowy issue of mine (...I know...but that is where I am at right now...terrible jokes.)

A little back ground: I am trying to write a simple program "mksuid" that will (among a few other things) ask the user for their password. The password will then be verified against the shadow file. If, everything jives, the the program can continue, otherwise it exits.

I want to gain an understanding on how to get a password from a user and verify that it is good to go. So, here is where I am at...

I am trying to get [this](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Shadow-Password-HOWTO-8.html) example off the ground, but am struggling on how to compile it.

I followed all* the instructions provided and have a simple driver calling the function *login()*. I then gcc:

```
sudo gcc mksuid.c -lshadow -I.. -D_linux_=1 -DGIDSET_TYPE=gid_t -DUSE_SHADOW
```

I get this back:

```
mksuid.c:6:27: fatal error: shadow/shadow.h: No such file or directory
#include <shadow/shadow.h>
                       ^
```

compilation terminated.

I have tried just #including shadow.h, but it (unsurprisingly) throws a fit because it doesn't know where to find anything.

I am having a hard time finding good examples to help me accomplish my goal. Thanks for the help!

*I did NOT go through all the steps of installing the shadow suite. I assume that my distro has it because I have a shadow file that is properly populated in my etc/. Maybe this is flawed logic. If so, let me know.

Comment: On Fedora Core 23 it appears to be just `<shadow.h>`, not `<shadow/shadow.h>`

Comment: hmm...I am starting to think that I am barking up the wrong tree... maybe there is a better example out there to help me verify a users password???

Comment: You might lack the development version of the shadow suite (indeed, most distros have the shadow library)

Comment: Why are you compiling as root? You should never have to do that.

Comment: It might be better to explain what you're trying to achieve with your program. Why not use `su`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working example using libpam, which is a bit higher level than shadow:

```
#include <security/pam_appl.h>
#include <security/pam_misc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  /* Read the username from command line           */
  argc--, argv++;
  if (argc != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Please provide the username as the first CLI argument.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  char *username = argv[0];

  pam_handle_t* pamh;
  struct pam_conv pamc;

  /* Set up the PAM conversation.                  */
  pamc.conv = &misc_conv;
  pamc.appdata_ptr = NULL;
  /* Start a new authentication session.           */
  pam_start("su", username, &pamc, &pamh);
  /* Authenticate the user.                        */
  if (pam_authenticate(pamh, 0) != PAM_SUCCESS)
    fprintf(stderr, "Authentication failed!\n");
  else
    fprintf(stderr, "Authentication OK.\n");
  /* All done.                                     */
  pam_end(pamh, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Reference: http://www.makelinux.net/alp/084

Dependency: `libpam0g-dev` on Debian/Ubuntu.

Compilation: `gcc -o pam pam.c -lpam -lpam_misc`.

Note that it will only be able to authenticate yourself, not other users, unless you run it as root (either by setting it as SUID or by turning it into some sort of daemon).

That means great care should be taken so that it is not vulnerable. It takes experience to do that. I mean no offense, but from what you are saying, you shouldn't be doing this.

Why not use a script based on `su` or `openssh` instead?

Comment: Just a note, not something critical: your return to the shell in the event of failure should be a positive value within the range of `unsigned char`. See [**Chapter 6. Exit and Exit Status**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html).

Comment: Thanks, fixed now.